# Facebook page like counts

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, coding-style, facebook-fql, facebook-page

how to put this into a <script> or javascript setup

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=select+fan_count+from+page+where+page_id%3D80177638103
```

that will return the fan_count nos. to a page.

```
<p> fan_count </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you you just want to use plain javascript then you can use

```
<script>
    function showCount(count){
        if(count)
            document.getElementById('fb_fan_count').innerHTML = 'Total fans : ' + count[0].fan_count;
    }
</script>
<p id="fb_fan_count"></p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&callback=showCount&query=select+fan_count+from+page+where+page_id%3D80177638103"></script>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7NMnJ/12/).

Comment: How/where did you use it ?

Comment: i upload on dropbxo - its here https://dl.dropbox.com/u/50980693/Fancount-stackoverflow.html

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this but something like this should do the trick. You might just have to replace the `results.fan_count` with the correct object name that Facebook outputs.

```
$.getJSON('https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=select+fan_count+from+page+where+page_id%3D80177638103', function( results ) {
    $('body').html(
        $.map( results.fan_count, function( obj, index ) {
            return '<p>' + obj.text + '</p>'
        }).join('')
    );
});
```